# Incorrect Multi-byte Character Width

Tags: php, utf-8, multibyte

I have encountered something bizarre in the mb_strwidth function; it may be a bug but I thought it better to ask here first in case I'm missing something.

**Context**

A class is being used to represent a generic string and is both iterable and seekable; with both iterations and seeks applying to the character within the string. The string has full multi-byte support, so when a new position is sought, it not only stores the character position, but recalculates the byte position in the string; like so:

```
$this->posByte = mb_strwidth(
    mb_substr($this->value, 0, $pos, $this->charEncoding), 
    $this->charEncoding
)
```

**Perceived Error**

However, when a multi-byte character is introduced, this is returning an incorrect value. The test case is this:

```
$str = string('The simple sentence of the simple man; here are some multi-byte chars: Øðćă.', 'UTF-8')
$str->seek(72);
```

This seeks to the second multi-byte character 'ð', but the byte calculation given above returns 72, the same as the character position; whereas it should be 73 since the preceding character 'Ø' has a code point of U+00D8; which is 216 in decimal and firmly in the two-byte character range.

This is confirmed by using the multi-byte unaware function strlen() (since I have not enabled mb overloading); which simply counts the number of bytes in a string. This:

```
$bytePos = strlen(mb_substr($this->value, 0, $pos, $this->charEncoding));
```

returns 73 as expected.

**Is this a known problem?**

I can use strlen() for now as a workaround, but I don't particularly like doing so since enabling multi-byte overloading in the PHP config would then cause the errors to reappear; does anyone have any experience of a similar issue? Is PHP just using an out-of-date character mapping?

For the record, this is from a PHPUnit test run on a PHP 5.6.3 windows environment.

Comment: `mb_strwidth` likely does not do what you think it does. It has nothing to do with bytes, it merely gives you the **visual width** of the character according to a fixed table.

Comment: @deceze Aah... from one of the comments in the PHP doc, you are correct. Apparently it is returning the number of character widths if displayed in monotype; I presume this is a reference to characters like the full-width (as opposed to half-width) Japanese characters. I completely misread the PHP manual page when I first looked at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be misinterpreting the function of `mb_strwidth`. Its purpose has nothing to do with bytes, it merely gives you the **visual width** of a string according to a fixed table. This is purely interesting for Asian character sets with appropriate monospaced fonts, where latin characters, commas and other punctation are half-width and "regular" characters are full-width. Everything up to and including U+1FFF is `1`.

You need to use `strlen` and other encoding-unaware functions to operate on strings in bytes, and mb_ functions to operate on them on a character level, to figure out your byte/character relationships.

If you're worried about the barbaric mb-overloading, either check the ini setting and refuse operation on insane systems, or use `mb_strlen` with a single-byte encoding set.

Comment: Thank you very much; now I feel foolish. Still, at least this has corrected my misunderstanding of mb_strwidth()